# How to know about jsf 'View Technology' Being used

Tags: jsf

i am new to  jsf. I am presently learning from an already developed project in jsf 1.2 using richfaces 3. But how to know what 'View Technology' is being used by this project ? i.e Jsp 2.x or facelet etcetra.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the view pages. If they're ' *.jsp' suffixed or, in contrary,  ' *.xhtml'.

Comment: so they are '*.jsp' means the view technology is 'jsp 2.x' if they were '*.xhtml' then what the view technology would have been?

Comment: In jsf 1.2 the default view technology is .jsp and in jsf 2.x it is .xhtml